The Raspberry Pi 3B+ and the stm32 also encountered an error when communicating
I’m working on a project that involves communication via UART between a Raspberry Pi 3B and an STM32F103 microcontroller. Here’s a brief overview of the task:
The Raspberry Pi performs object recognition using YOLO and sends the recognized label names through UART to the STM32, which then processes them accordingly. The goal is to establish communication between the two devices.
However, during operation, I encounter an issue where after recognizing approximately 6 to 10 images, the UART connection seems to disconnect. It’s puzzling why this sudden disconnection occurs, and I’m unable to resolve it. I seek your assistance.
Here is the error message from the Raspberry Pi during operation (communication was initially normal but later encountered issues). Just to clarify, I’ve added UART transmission of recognized labels as a simple addition to the existing setup.
    video 1/1 (10/6225) /home/pi/Desktop/TieandMan.mp4: 384x640 1 mouse, 2636.3ms
person
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/serial/serialposix.py", line 603, in write
    n = os.write(self.fd, d)
OSError: [Errno 5] Input/output error

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/pi/Desktop/yolov5-master /detect.py", line 279, in <module>
    main(opt)           # 自定义的main
  File "/home/pi/Desktop/yolov5-master /detect.py", line 274, in main
    run(**vars(opt))
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/dist-packages/torch/utils/_contextlib.py", line 115, in decorate_context
    return func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/pi/Desktop/yolov5-master /detect.py", line 186, in run
    ser.write('@'.encode('utf-8'))
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/serial/serialposix.py", line 637, in write
    raise SerialException('write failed: {}'.format(e))
serial.serialutil.SerialException: write failed: [Errno 5] Input/output error

This is the modified detect.py code from my YOLO implementation.
# YOLOv5  by Ultralytics, GPL-3.0 license
"""
Run YOLOv5 detection inference on images, videos, directories, globs, YouTube, webcam, streams, etc.

Usage - sources:
    $ python detect.py --weights yolov5s.pt --source 0                               # webcam
                                                     img.jpg                         # image
                                                     vid.mp4                         # video
                                                     path/                           # directory
                                                     'path/*.jpg'                    # glob
                                                     'https://youtu.be/Zgi9g1ksQHc'  # YouTube
                                                     'rtsp://example.com/media.mp4'  # RTSP, RTMP, HTTP stream

Usage - formats:
    $ python detect.py --weights yolov5s.pt                 # PyTorch
                                 yolov5s.torchscript        # TorchScript
                                 yolov5s.onnx               # ONNX Runtime or OpenCV DNN with --dnn
                                 yolov5s_openvino_model     # OpenVINO
                                 yolov5s.engine             # TensorRT
                                 yolov5s.mlmodel            # CoreML (macOS-only)
                                 yolov5s_saved_model        # TensorFlow SavedModel
                                 yolov5s.pb                 # TensorFlow GraphDef
                                 yolov5s.tflite             # TensorFlow Lite
                                 yolov5s_edgetpu.tflite     # TensorFlow Edge TPU
                                 yolov5s_paddle_model       # PaddlePaddle
"""

import argparse
import os
import platform
import sys
from pathlib import Path
import serial

import torch

FILE = Path(__file__).resolve() # D:\yolov5-master\detect.py【绝对路径】
ROOT = FILE.parents[0]  # YOLOv5 root directory,D\yolov5-master【相对路径】
if str(ROOT) not in sys.path:   # 如果查询的模块不在根目录下D\yolov5-master，再次导入
    sys.path.append(str(ROOT))  # add ROOT to PATH
ROOT = Path(os.path.relpath(ROOT, Path.cwd()))  # relative，绝对路径转换成相对路径

from models.common import DetectMultiBackend
from utils.dataloaders import IMG_FORMATS, VID_FORMATS, LoadImages, LoadScreenshots, LoadStreams
from utils.general import (LOGGER, Profile, check_file, check_img_size, check_imshow, check_requirements, colorstr, cv2,
                           increment_path, non_max_suppression, print_args, scale_boxes, strip_optimizer, xyxy2xywh)
from utils.plots import Annotator, colors, save_one_box
from utils.torch_utils import select_device, smart_inference_mode


@smart_inference_mode()
def run(
        weights=ROOT / 'yolov5s.pt',  # model path or triton URL
        source=0,  # file/dir/URL/glob/screen/0(webcam) ROOT / 'data/images'
        data=ROOT / 'data/coco128.yaml',  # dataset.yaml path
        imgsz=(640, 640),  # inference size (height, width)
        conf_thres=0.25,  # confidence threshold
        iou_thres=0.45,  # NMS IOU threshold
        max_det=1000,  # maximum detections per image
        device='',  # cuda device, i.e. 0 or 0,1,2,3 or cpu
        view_img=False,  # show results
        save_txt=False,  # save results to *.txt
        save_conf=False,  # save confidences in --save-txt labels
        save_crop=False,  # save cropped prediction boxes
        nosave=False,  # do not save images/videos
        classes=None,  # filter by class: --class 0, or --class 0 2 3
        agnostic_nms=False,  # class-agnostic NMS
        augment=False,  # augmented inference
        visualize=False,  # visualize features
        update=False,  # update all models
        project=ROOT / 'runs/detect',  # save results to project/name
        name='exp',  # save results to project/name
        exist_ok=False,  # existing project/name ok, do not increment
        line_thickness=3,  # bounding box thickness (pixels)
        hide_labels=False,  # hide labels
        hide_conf=False,  # hide confidences
        half=False,  # use FP16 half-precision inference
        dnn=False,  # use OpenCV DNN for ONNX inference
        vid_stride=1,  # video frame-rate stride
        # TODO 0、这里需要修改测试串口能不能用
        serial_port=None,  # serial port from raspberryPi to stm32
):
    source = str(source)
    save_img = not nosave and not source.endswith('.txt')  # save inference images
    is_file = Path(source).suffix[1:] in (IMG_FORMATS + VID_FORMATS)
    is_url = source.lower().startswith(('rtsp://', 'rtmp://', 'http://', 'https://'))
    webcam = source.isnumeric() or source.endswith('.txt') or (is_url and not is_file)
    screenshot = source.lower().startswith('screen')
    if is_url and is_file:
        source = check_file(source)  # download


    # TODO 1、打开串口
    ser = serial.Serial('/dev/ttyAMA0', 115200)
    if ser.isOpen == False:
        ser.open()                # 打开串口
    # ser.write(b"Raspberry pi is ready")



    # Directories
    save_dir = increment_path(Path(project) / name, exist_ok=exist_ok)  # increment run
    (save_dir / 'labels' if save_txt else save_dir).mkdir(parents=True, exist_ok=True)  # make dir

    # Load model
    device = select_device(device)
    model = DetectMultiBackend(weights, device=device, dnn=dnn, data=data, fp16=half)
    stride, names, pt = model.stride, model.names, model.pt
    imgsz = check_img_size(imgsz, s=stride)  # check image size

    # 数据加载器
    bs = 1  # batch_size
    if webcam:
        view_img = check_imshow(warn=True)
        dataset = LoadStreams(source, img_size=imgsz, stride=stride, auto=pt, vid_stride=vid_stride)
        bs = len(dataset)
    elif screenshot:
        dataset = LoadScreenshots(source, img_size=imgsz, stride=stride, auto=pt)
    else:
        dataset = LoadImages(source, img_size=imgsz, stride=stride, auto=pt, vid_stride=vid_stride)
    vid_path, vid_writer = [None] * bs, [None] * bs

    # Run inference
    model.warmup(imgsz=(1 if pt or model.triton else bs, 3, *imgsz))  # warmup
    seen, windows, dt = 0, [], (Profile(), Profile(), Profile())
    for path, im, im0s, vid_cap, s in dataset:
        with dt[0]:
            im = torch.from_numpy(im).to(model.device)
            im = im.half() if model.fp16 else im.float()  # uint8 to fp16/32
            im /= 255  # 0 - 255 to 0.0 - 1.0
            if len(im.shape) == 3:
                im = im[None]  # expand for batch dim

        # Inference
        with dt[1]:
            visualize = increment_path(save_dir / Path(path).stem, mkdir=True) if visualize else False
            # 进行模型推理
            pred = model(im, augment=augment, visualize=visualize)

        # NMS
        with dt[2]:
            pred = non_max_suppression(pred, conf_thres, iou_thres, classes, agnostic_nms, max_det=max_det)


        # Second-stage classifier (optional)
        # pred = utils.general.apply_classifier(pred, classifier_model, im, im0s)

        # Process predictions
        for i, det in enumerate(pred):  # per image
            seen += 1
            if webcam:  # batch_size >= 1
                p, im0, frame = path[i], im0s[i].copy(), dataset.count
                s += f'{i}: '
            else:
                p, im0, frame = path, im0s.copy(), getattr(dataset, 'frame', 0)

            p = Path(p)  # to Path
            save_path = str(save_dir / p.name)  # im.jpg
            txt_path = str(save_dir / 'labels' / p.stem) + ('' if dataset.mode == 'image' else f'_{frame}')  # im.txt
            s += '%gx%g ' % im.shape[2:]  # print string
            gn = torch.tensor(im0.shape)[[1, 0, 1, 0]]  # normalization gain whwh
            imc = im0.copy() if save_crop else im0  # for save_crop
            annotator = Annotator(im0, line_width=line_thickness, example=str(names))
            if len(det):
                # Rescale boxes from img_size to im0 size
                det[:, :4] = scale_boxes(im.shape[2:], det[:, :4], im0.shape).round()

                # Print results
                for c in det[:, 5].unique():
                    n = (det[:, 5] == c).sum()  # detections per class
                    s += f"{n} {names[int(c)]}{'s' * (n > 1)}, "  # add to string

                # 写入结果
                for *xyxy, conf, cls in reversed (det) :
                    if save_txt :  # 将结果写入文件
                        xywh = (xyxy2xywh(torch.tensor(xyxy).view (1, 4)) / gn).view (-1).tolist()  # 归一化 xywh
                        line = (cls, *xywh, conf) if save_conf else (cls, *xywh)  # 标签格式
                        with open ( f'{txt_path}.txt', 'a' ) as f :
                            f.write(('%g ' * len(line)).rstrip () % line + '\n' )

                    if save_img or save_crop or view_img :  # 在图像上添加边框
                        c = int(cls)  # 整数类别
                        label = None if hide_labels else (names[c] if hide_conf else f'{names[c]} {conf:.2f}')
                        surper_label = names[c]
                        ser.write('@'.encode())
                        ser.write(surper_label.encode())
                        # 发送换行符（ASCII码为10），用于换行
                        ser.write('\r\n'.encode())
                        print("result label is---")
                        print(surper_label)
                        print('\r\n')
                        # print(label)
                        annotator.box_label (xyxy, label, color=colors(c, True ))  # 添加边框
                    if save_crop :
                        save_one_box(xyxy, imc, file=save_dir / 'crops' / names[c] / f'{p.stem}.jpg', BGR=True )

            # Stream results
            im0 = annotator.result()
            if view_img:
                if platform.system() == 'Linux' and p not in windows:
                    windows.append(p)
                    cv2.namedWindow(str(p), cv2.WINDOW_NORMAL | cv2.WINDOW_KEEPRATIO)  # allow window resize (Linux)
                    cv2.resizeWindow(str(p), im0.shape[1], im0.shape[0])
                cv2.imshow(str(p), im0)
                cv2.waitKey(1)  # 1 millisecond

            # Save results (image with detections)
            if save_img:
                if dataset.mode == 'image':
                    cv2.imwrite(save_path, im0)
                else:  # 'video' or 'stream'
                    if vid_path[i] != save_path:  # new video
                        vid_path[i] = save_path
                        if isinstance(vid_writer[i], cv2.VideoWriter):
                            vid_writer[i].release()  # release previous video writer
                        if vid_cap:  # video
                            fps = vid_cap.get(cv2.CAP_PROP_FPS)
                            w = int(vid_cap.get(cv2.CAP_PROP_FRAME_WIDTH))
                            h = int(vid_cap.get(cv2.CAP_PROP_FRAME_HEIGHT))
                        else:  # stream
                            fps, w, h = 30, im0.shape[1], im0.shape[0]
                        save_path = str(Path(save_path).with_suffix('.mp4'))  # force *.mp4 suffix on results videos
                        vid_writer[i] = cv2.VideoWriter(save_path, cv2.VideoWriter_fourcc(*'mp4v'), fps, (w, h))
                    vid_writer[i].write(im0)

        # Print time (inference-only)
        LOGGER.info(f"{s}{'' if len(det) else '(no detections), '}{dt[1].dt * 1E3:.1f}ms")

    # Print results
    t = tuple(x.t / seen * 1E3 for x in dt)  # speeds per image
    LOGGER.info(f'Speed: %.1fms pre-process, %.1fms inference, %.1fms NMS per image at shape {(1, 3, *imgsz)}' % t)
    if save_txt or save_img:
        s = f"\n{len(list(save_dir.glob('labels/*.txt')))} labels saved to {save_dir / 'labels'}" if save_txt else ''
        LOGGER.info(f"Results saved to {colorstr('bold', save_dir)}{s}")
    if update:
        strip_optimizer(weights[0])  # update model (to fix SourceChangeWarning)


def parse_opt():
    parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
    parser.add_argument('--weights', nargs='+', type=str, default=ROOT / 'yolov5s.pt', help='model path or triton URL')
    parser.add_argument('--source', type=str, default=ROOT / 'data/images', help='file/dir/URL/glob/screen/0(webcam)')
    parser.add_argument('--data', type=str, default=ROOT / 'data/coco128.yaml', help='(optional) dataset.yaml path')
    parser.add_argument('--imgsz', '--img', '--img-size', nargs='+', type=int, default=[640], help='inference size h,w')
    parser.add_argument('--conf-thres', type=float, default=0.25, help='confidence threshold')
    parser.add_argument('--iou-thres', type=float, default=0.45, help='NMS IoU threshold')
    parser.add_argument('--max-det', type=int, default=1000, help='maximum detections per image')
    parser.add_argument('--device', default='', help='cuda device, i.e. 0 or 0,1,2,3 or cpu')
    parser.add_argument('--view-img', action='store_true', help='show results')
    parser.add_argument('--save-txt', action='store_true', help='save results to *.txt')
    parser.add_argument('--save-conf', action='store_true', help='save confidences in --save-txt labels')
    parser.add_argument('--save-crop', action='store_true', help='save cropped prediction boxes')
    parser.add_argument('--nosave', action='store_true', help='do not save images/videos')
    parser.add_argument('--classes', nargs='+', type=int, help='filter by class: --classes 0, or --classes 0 2 3')
    parser.add_argument('--agnostic-nms', action='store_true', help='class-agnostic NMS')
    parser.add_argument('--augment', action='store_true', help='augmented inference')
    parser.add_argument('--visualize', action='store_true', help='visualize features')
    parser.add_argument('--update', action='store_true', help='update all models')
    parser.add_argument('--project', default=ROOT / 'runs/detect', help='save results to project/name')
    parser.add_argument('--name', default='exp', help='save results to project/name')
    parser.add_argument('--exist-ok', action='store_true', help='existing project/name ok, do not increment')
    parser.add_argument('--line-thickness', default=3, type=int, help='bounding box thickness (pixels)')
    parser.add_argument('--hide-labels', default=False, action='store_true', help='hide labels')
    parser.add_argument('--hide-conf', default=False, action='store_true', help='hide confidences')
    parser.add_argument('--half', action='store_true', help='use FP16 half-precision inference')
    parser.add_argument('--dnn', action='store_true', help='use OpenCV DNN for ONNX inference')
    parser.add_argument('--vid-stride', type=int, default=1, help='video frame-rate stride')
    opt = parser.parse_args()
    opt.imgsz *= 2 if len(opt.imgsz) == 1 else 1  # expand
    # print_args(vars(opt))
    return opt


def main(opt):
    check_requirements(exclude=('tensorboard', 'thop')) # 检测依赖包
    run(**vars(opt))


if __name__ == "__main__":
    opt = parse_opt()   # 解析导入的参数
    main(opt)           # 自定义的main

This is the main function of my STM32 part (It implements the function of judging the incoming data frame and displaying corresponding LED blinking).
#include "stm32f10x.h"
#include <string.h>     // Include this for strcmp without warning
#include "USART.h"
#include "LED.h"
#include "Delay.h"
#include <stdlib.h>

uint8_t Data;           // Receive one byte of data
unsigned char RX_Str[100];
const char* c = (const char*)RX_Str;            // Data format for strcmp
u16 Rx_FLAG = 0;         
int main(void)
{
    
    USART1_Config();
    LED_Init();
    
    LED1_OFF();
    LED2_OFF();
    
    while(1)
    {

        if(Rx_FLAG==1) // Receive complete flag Rx_FLAG is 1
        {
            if(strcmp(c,"person")==0) // Compare received characters for "person"
            {
                LED1_ON();  
                LED2_OFF();
                printf("Recognition result is person \r\n"); // Print red LED on information
            }
            else if(strcmp(c,"tie")==0) // Compare received characters for "tie"
            {
                LED1_OFF();
                LED2_ON();
                printf("Recognition result is tie \r\n"); // Print blue LED on information
            }
            else                                // If input command does not match
            {
                LED1_ON();      // Light up LEDs
                LED2_ON();
                printf("Input command error!! \r\n"); // Print input command error
            }
            Rx_FLAG=0; // Reset receive complete flag
        }
    }
}

void USART1_IRQHandler(void)    // USART interrupt function
{
    static u16 RX_zt;       // USART receive status
    static u16 i;           // Character array index
    if (USART_GetITStatus(USART1, USART_IT_RXNE)==SET) // When receive flag is SET, start receiving
    {
        Data=USART_ReceiveData(USART1); // Receive data
        if(RX_zt==0)                    // If USART receive status is 0
        {
            if(Data=='@'&&Rx_FLAG==0)   // Check if received data is header @, and Rx_FLAG=0 to prevent data corruption during fast transmission
            {
                RX_zt=1;             // Change to status 1
                i=0;                 // Reset character array index
            }
        }
        // DATA \r\n
        else if(RX_zt==1)           // If USART receive status is 1
        {
            if(Data=='\r')          // Check if it's end of packet character
            {
                RX_zt=2;            // Change to status 2
            }
            else
            {
                RX_Str[i]=Data;     // Store received data into character array
                i++;
            }
        }
        else if(RX_zt==2)           // If USART receive status is 2
        {
            if(Data=='\n')          // Check again if it's end of packet character
            {
                RX_zt=0;            // Change to status 0
                RX_Str[i]='\0';     // End of string reception
                Rx_FLAG=1;          // Set receive complete flag
            }
        }

        USART_ClearITPendingBit(USART1, USART_IT_RXNE); // Clear receive flag
    }
}


Today, through the test, it was found that the Raspberry Pi and 32 communication could not work because of the problem of 32, or because of the use
The communication process is very unstable.
Here's a quick rundown of today's test:
First of all, the Raspberry Pi sent a message to the computer serial assistant all the time,
It lasts for about 4min, and the signal can be sent all the time; (15 mins start)
However, when connected to the board, there will still be an exception that the serial port cannot be opened during data transmission.
Attempts to modify the baud rate and increase the various data of the serial port are unsuccessful.
By the way, except for 115200, none of the other baud rates succeeded in getting 32 lights up more than once, and they were all just stuck in the first group.
Try to follow the teaching of AI to open all kinds of permissions, but it is useless!
Ultimately.
In the process of communicating between the Raspberry Pi and the computer, Hand Yau used the serial port assistant to send a set of data to the Raspberry Pi
Resulting in garbled characters, so it is speculated that there may be some irresistible interference between the 32 and Raspberry Pi communication processes.
